# Архитектура клиентского приложения Android для интернет магазина

Tags: java, android, android-studio, rest

Есть интернет-магазин, нужно написать для него приложение, а точнее для работы с его админкой. 
Основными функциями должны быть:

- добавление/изменение/удаление товаров
- просмотр списка заказов
- просмотр категорий/подкатегорий/товаров в виде дерева или каких-то
  выпадающих списков

В качестве обмена данными с сервером используются REST API. В ответ сервер отдает JSON.

Для выполнения запросов использую ApacheHttpClient (смотрю в сторону библиотеки Volley). Для этого у меня создан класс со статическими переменными и методами для каждого запроса.

На данном этапе интересует следующее:
в главном Активити есть кнопка "получить древо категорий" —» вызывается класс со статическим методом для данного запроса —» в ответ получаю JSON-ом список категорий/ подкатегорий.

[image: дерево проекта]

Коротко о работе приложения:
В MainActivity пользователь нажимает на кнопку найти товар по id -->> вызывается  асинхронный запрос который обращается к статическому методу класса API.getProductById(String id) -->> метод посылает нужный запрос на сервер  и получает от него ответ -->> далее метод .getProductById(String id) отправляет ответ в MainActivity -->> в MainActivity формируется интент с получеными данными и отправляется в нужную активити где и отображаются данные для пользователя.

Вопросы:

1) правильный ли я использую подход для выполнения запросов?

2) как поступить с полученным ответом, где и как его лучше хранить, возможно использовать БД?

3) каким способом можно отобразить данное дерево в Активити, что бы при нажатии на товар я мог просмотреть о нем информацию?

- **КАТЕГОРИЯ**

  **-подкатегория**

  -товар

  -товар

  **-подкатегория**

  -товар

  -товар

4) Какая иерархия классов должна присутствовать в подобном приложении.

5) Так же интересует: архитектура подобных приложений и какие средства используются для их   реализации? Возможно какие-то примеры, литература...

P.S. Это первый опыт написания функционально приложения для Android с помощью Java, буду рад любой информации!

Comment: слишком много вопросов для одного поста. Кроме того, ни на один не существует правильного ответа.

Comment: Да,я понимаю! Меня интересуют любые альтернативы и советы, даже в отдельных аспектах, относительно чего либо в рамках данной задачи.

Comment: Тогда хорошо, чтобы вы прочитали еще и правила форума. О том, что вопросы, на которые нет однозначного ответа здесь задавать нельзя. А тем более вопросы, в которых по сути несколько вопросов.

Comment: Ну как обычно первый блин комом, я тут первый день, к следующему вопросу я подойду основательно!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы немного неверно строите архитектуру. Вам надо:

1. Вынести обращения к серваку в отдельный сервис, который крутится в своем потоке - см. в сторону `IntentService`
2. Полученые от Rest API данные надо складывать в SQLite БД, иначе если не будет коннекта или коннект будет медленный у вас ничего не будет показываться.
3. Показывать нужно всегда данные из БД, причем посредством `ContentProvider` над этим БД. `ContentProvider` должен давать вам `Cursor`, а от курсора вы должны рисовать уже свои деревья/списки.

В итоге получится так, что в фоне у вас будет крутиться сервис, который подсасывает данные из сервера и кладет в БД. Ну а поскольку над БД у вас будет развернут `ContentProvider` то все изменения которые будет вносить сервис в БД будет автоматом отображаться на UI.

Для рисования списков в последнее время модным стало использование `RecyclerView`, он лучше себя ведет в тяжелых списках с картинками, правда и кода он требует чуток больше чем `ListView`.

Как то так.